# An error with integer to string conversion

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, delphi-7

I am programming in Delphi 7 on Windows XP. This part of the program is defining a caption for the `opendialog` and I have a really strange problem.

The code with the error is as below

```
od_cap := 'Select data set ' + intToStr(n_data_sets);
```

where `od_cap` is a string and `n_data_sets` is an integer. The error that arises is `EAccessViolation at address 0040459a`... I have narrowed the problem down to being caused by the `inttostr` conversion because it still crashes when I have `od_cap := inttostr(2)`. The more strange thing is that first time it computes this line, it works but then crashes the 2nd time round every time.

I cannot think of any reason why this might be and I am not experienced enough to know any bugs that might cause this. I think this is all the information you should need but feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Does the error also show when you assign od_cap := '2'? Is this assignment the first assignment in a method or your classes?

Comment: How are you creating the TOpenDialog? Are you dropping it on the form as a component, or creating it in code?

Comment: Voted to close. Asker thinks the question has to do with integer-to-string conversion, but it clearly doesn't. Asker appears to have deleted his or her account, so there's no chance of getting further information to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

`IntToStr()` does not raise an AV during conversion.  What is more likely happening is the `od_cap` variable is not a valid `String` variable, such as if it is a member of an object that has been freed, so an AV occurs when it is assigned to.